# glmmTMB profile argument, what does it do?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, glmmtmb

I tried running analysis using glmmTMB with profile=TRUE and the model that previously wasn't converging, now converging, anyone knows what assumptions does this parameter "profile" takes and whether this is reliable?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.